# Is cognitive distortions more fixated than cognitive biases?

Tags: bias, belief, cognitive-distortion, epistemology, heuristics

I get that due to our [heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic), we can have [cognitive bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias). However, it is simply out of our awareness, and if someone else points them out correctly, we are easy to accept that (maybe with embarrassment, but it's still easy for the person having it to accept that they are wrong). On the other hand, [cognitive distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_distortion) seems like a different beast to me. They are more fixate, and I think it's not a stretch to call them a kind of defense mechanism (in fact, Beck created this as a reaction to his unsatisfaction to Freudian treatment of depression). So maybe it's harder for them to accept, and we may need other forms of persuasion, like peer pressure.

My questions:

- Is it correct that [beliefs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belief#Models_of_belief_formation) made from cognitive distortions are more likely to be fixated?
- If yes, then why is that? Is it because if the incorrect belief is found to be wrong, then the reconstructed, corrected version of a biased belief would be less likely to create [cognitive dissonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance) than the reconstructed, corrected version of a distorted belief?
- If yes, then it seems that the belief that is going to conflict with the reconstructed, corrected one is also strong. Can we say anything about it?

Comment: A belief resulting from lazy or hurried thinking can be changed if pointed out and given time for reflection. A belief resulting from emotional insecurity, in contrast, is going to persevere unless or until the dissonance of keeping it exceeds that of changing it. Remember however that not everything expressed is necessarily believed behind the mask. Sometimes a person is looking for validation or another reaction. Naturally a thinking pattern partaken repeatedly, whether from going too fast or for emotional reasons, is going to become more automatic over time, making it harder to change.